# Using Generics in Expressions for overloaded collection parameters

Tags: c#, generics

I have created a class which has a method which is overloaded to accept a class or a collection of classes.

The problem is that the wrong overload is called for different types of collections. An example of this can be seen using this sample code I've created:

```
void Main()
{
    GenericMethod(x => x.CollectionItems, ExpectedType.Collection);
    GenericMethod(x => x.ListItems, ExpectedType.Collection);
    GenericMethod(x => x.EnumerableItems, ExpectedType.Collection);
    GenericMethod(x => x.CollectionTestSubClass, ExpectedType.Single);
}

public void GenericMethod<TPropType>(Expression<Func<CollectionTestClass, TPropType>> predicate, ExpectedType expectedType) 
    where TPropType : class
{
    $"Single Method Called - Expected: {expectedType}".Dump();
}

public void GenericMethod<TPropType>(Expression<Func<CollectionTestClass, IEnumerable<TPropType>>> predicate, ExpectedType expectedType)
    where TPropType : class
{
    $"Collection Method Called - Expected: {expectedType}".Dump();
}

public class CollectionTestClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CollectionTestSubClass> CollectionItems { get; set; }
    public IList<CollectionTestSubClass> ListItems { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CollectionTestSubClass> EnumerableItems { get; set; }
    public CollectionTestSubClass CollectionTestSubClass { get; set; }
}

public class CollectionTestSubClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public enum ExpectedType
{
    Single,
    Collection
}
```

The output will be:

[image: Code output]

So it is only the IEnumerable that will call the correct `Collection` method.

I would have thought that with ICollection and IList being implementations of IEnumerable that it may be able to figure out which method to call. Or is it a case that generics in C# are constraining to the point that even though other collections do implement `IEnumerable` it is only going to allow the explicit class specified to be used?

In which case would I have to write a overload for each collection type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overload of generic method for IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39943036/overload-of-generic-method-for-ienumerablet)